# The Random Walk in Feynman's Lectures of Physics

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

The distances in the random walk are unit positive or negative.

In the calculation for the distance, $D_N$ traveled after $N$ steps, the author uses $D_N^2$ instead of $D_N$. [From The Feynman Lectures on Physics, Part 1](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_06.html),

> The expected value of $D^2_N$ for $N>1$ can be obtained from $D_{N−1}$. If, after $(N−1)$ steps, we have $D_{N−1}$, then after $N$ steps we have $D_N=D_{N−1}+1$ or $D_N=D_{N−1}−1$. For the squares,
> $$D^2_N = \begin{cases} D^2_{N-1} + 2 D_{N-1} + 1\\ \quad\quad or\\ D^2_{N-1} - 2 D_{N-1} + 1\end{cases}$$
> In a number of independent sequences, we expect to obtain each value one-half of the time, so our average expectation is just the average of the two possible values. The expected value of $D^2_N$ is then $D^2_{N−1}+1$. In general, we should expect for $D^2_{N−1}$ its “expected value” $\left\langle D^2_{N−1} \right\rangle$ (by definition!). So
> $$\left\langle D^2_N \right\rangle = \left\langle D^2_{N−1} \right\rangle + 1$$
> We have already shown that $\left\langle D^2_1 \right\rangle=1$; it follows then that
> $$\left\langle D^2_N \right\rangle = N$$

If I take $$  D_N =
\begin{cases}
D_{N-1} - 1,  & \\
or & \\
D_{N-1} + 1. &
\end{cases}$$

and then average out both of them to obtain $\langle D_N\rangle = \langle D_{N-1}\rangle$.
So this results in $\langle D_N\rangle = +1$ or $-1$ (because $D_1 = +1$ or $-1$) as opposed to the given $\sqrt N$.

Where in my idea did I go wrong?

Comment: Please note that using images to quote text and math is very strongly discouraged on Physics SE.  Please use a combination of text and [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which is the site standard for mathematical expressions.

Comment: There is an answer in the linked post that addresses the issue of the random walk, by finding the average of $n$ unit vectors with random angle.

Comment: @StephenG I'm not a big fan of imagery as imagery can make a question or answer inaccessible. This is particularly so for snapped images. So I fixed it.

Comment: @VincentThacker Related but not a duplicate.

Comment: @Vincent Thacker I found that actually to be similar to what I knew. I couldn't find where I was wrong in first sight. After reading the answer by Philip to this question and then going there it did strike to me.

Answer (score 4):

There are some problems with your analysis. First of all, the quantity $\langle D_n \rangle$ is the mean displacement (from the origin) as a function of the steps $n$.  Since the random walker is just as likely to turn left as right, it should be intuitive to you that $\langle D_n \rangle = 0$, rather than $1$, as you claim. I'm guessing that you have misunderstood what the "average" means in this case. The averages that are being taken here are over many different "realisations". In other words, you repeat the random-walker experiment many times, and at each time you measure the value of a particular quantity (say, $Q$). You then average over these quantities to get $\langle Q \rangle$.

As you have rightly pointed out, at the start, $D_1 = +1$ or $-1$ with equal probability. As a result, if you repeated the experiment many times, half the times the first step of the walker would be to the left ("$-1$"), and the other half it would be to the right ("$+1$"). This means that $$\langle D_1 \rangle = 0,$$ since that is the "expected" value. From this, you should be able to see that $\langle D_n \rangle = 0$.

The quantity that the author is computing, however, is more interesting: it is the mean **distance** covered by the random walker in $n$ steps. Since this quantity is independent of the direction in which each step is taken, one way to measure it would be to take the *square* of the variable $D_n$ and then compute the mean, i.e. $\langle D_n^2\rangle$. You could then take the square root of the resulting quantity to get an answer with dimensions of length. This is called the root-mean-square distance.

In general, for any randomly distributed variable $X$, $$\langle X \rangle^2 \neq \langle X^2 \rangle.$$ (You can easily check this by choosing a bunch of negative random numbers and computing their mean, and the mean of the squares. One will be negative, and the other positive!)

As a result, $\langle D_n \rangle ^2 \neq \langle D_n^2 \rangle$, so there is no contradiction.

Comment: I am particularly new to asking questions here. I could get my mistake only after reading this answer and the suggested similar question made any sense to me only after reading this. Should I delete this question as suggested to me by Stack Exchange?

Comment: To be fair, I don't think this question is a duplicate. I'm sure there's some similarity to the linked question, and in that sense it is related, but that's as far as it goes. I think many people who come to this question because they have similar issues will not be able to get an answer by just looking at this so-called "duplicate". As a result, I would suggest that you not delete this question. I have voted to reopen it, perhaps other users will agree.